# Mapping contents of <td> elements to array using id attribute

Tags: jquery, html, dom, html-table

I'm trying to map  elements in a table to elements of an array so user can edit  contents, see the result in the table - and the array is updated. I'd like to use the simple array[row][col] notation to access the array. So I assigned id's to each  element from id="0-0" to id="99-9". I'm using code like:

```
r=0;c=4;
rowStr+= "<td id='"+r+"-"+c+"'></td>";
// HTML shows: <td id="0-4" </td> etc.
```

This works fine. I can log the id's to my console as I create them and they show in the page when I examine the HTML in my debugger as shown in the comment above.

But I can't use the id's to access/edit the cell contents no matter what I do. I tried jQuery:

```
var idStr="#id"+r+"-"+c; $(idStr).text("content");
```

. .  and HTML Dom methods:

```
document.getElementById("0-4").innerHTML="content";
```

In both cases the code halts and I get debugger error:

```
Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: '#0-4'
```

Thanks in advance for anyone who can tell me what's happening here.

Comment: I'm not sure about this, but I think there might be a problem with the first char being a digit. Try using a prefix.

Comment: `id` cannot start with number.

Comment: Also, in jQuery, you don't need the single quotes inside the selector string.

Comment: IDs **can** start with a number in HTML5.

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle showing the problem?

Comment: @Asad Thanks. I thought I read that somewhere. So I also tried: rowStr+= "<td id=r'r"+r+"-"+c+"'></td>"; to set the id. And var str="'#r"+r+"-"+c+"'"; to access it w/ $(str).text=("Content") the html shows" id="r0-4" but gives same error.

Comment: I don't understand why you have so many quotes for your selector string. You don't need the actual string to have any quotes inside it.

Comment: Yeah, I was trying every possible combination of chars. That's just my last attempt of many. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to make use of native HTMLTable API. It allows you to reference table cells and rows by their index. For example you can access the second TD element of the third row as

```
table.rows[2].cells[1].innerHTML = 'New content'; // index starts from 0
```

In this case you don't need bunch of ids.

You can even create a very simple helper function to select TD by indexes:

```
function getCell(row, cell) {
    return tableElement.rows[row].cells[cell];
}

getCell(2, 3).innerHTML = 'Cell 4 in third row';
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mQY5Z/

Comment: I re-wrote the code using the advice you offered here and I can now access the table. Also, I did not have to assign id's to the <td> elements. I suspect this will be even faster since no need to call any jQuery functions. It's surprising to me that I never saw this approach in any of the searches I ran. Thanks for showing me this important technique to know. I'm not sure what it means if I "accept" an answer but I see some folks explicitly do that. So, yes, I accept this great answer.

Comment: @Banjobum To "accept" an answer, you would click the checkmark next to it. This indicates to anyone who comes across your question in the future that this answer helped you solve your problem. It also puts this answer at the top of the answer list, so people can find it more quickly.

Comment: Thanks Asad! I looked for a button someplace. And thanks for your advice. It helped.